# Facebook live stream api not working with ffmpeg

Tags: facebook, ffmpeg, facebook-live-api

I am trying to stream to facebook via ffmpeg via the facebook api and it is not working.
when I try to stream to facebook via the facebook streaming key in the facebook live console it works. this is my ffmpeg commend

```
ffmpeg -re -y -f pulse -ac 2 -i default -f x11grab -video_size 1280x720 -draw_mouse 0 -i :44 -filter_complex "[1:v]split=2[s0][s1];[s0]scale=1280:-2[v0];[s1]scale=1280:-2[v1]" -map "[v0]" -map "[v1]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset medium -b:v 4M -maxrate 4M -bufsize 8M -framerate 24 -strict -2 -g 48 -r 24 -flags +global_header -f tee "[select=\\\'v:0,a\\\':f=mp4:onfail=ignore]/var/archives/5d47b5cc65f4e15d7d850a94/2022/2/24/6217260a2d3a6c51d22b3f9e/master/1645684234.mp4|[select=\\\'v:1,a\\\':f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/******?*****"
```

In this commend, I am also recording and able to stream to multiple streams (facebook, youtube)

full report

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.2-0york0~18.04 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='0york0~18.04' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libzimg --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, pulse, from 'default':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1645702690.343393, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
[x11grab @ 0x55e6c5a5c300] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #1, x11grab, from ':44':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1645702690.400818, bitrate: 883852 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1280x720, 883852 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 (rawvideo) -> split (graph 0)
  scale (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  scale (graph 0) -> Stream #0:1 (libx264)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:2 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x55e6c5a6a580] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x55e6c5a6a580] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x55e6c5a6a580] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=48 keyint_min=4 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=cbr mbtree=1 bitrate=4000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=4000 vbv_bufsize=8000 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[libx264 @ 0x55e6c5a6bb00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x55e6c5a6bb00] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x55e6c5a6bb00] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=48 keyint_min=4 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=cbr mbtree=1 bitrate=4000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=4000 vbv_bufsize=8000 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[tee @ 0x55e6c5a68c40] Slave '[select='v:1,a':f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/4793731374078228?s_bl=1&s_oil=2&s_oilp=videoinfra_live_multi_e2o_2_vcache_pull_prod_&s_oilu=videoinfra_live_e2o_poc&s_ow=20&s_psm=1&s_r2f=1&s_sw=0&s_tids=1&s_vt=api-s&a=Abx_7pAPml40PHTg': error opening: Input/output error
[tee @ 0x55e6c5a68c40] Slave muxer #1 failed: Input/output error, continuing with 1/2 slaves.
[tee @ 0x55e6c5a68c40] Input stream #1 is not mapped to any slave.
Output #0, tee, to '[select=\'v:0,a\':f=mp4:onfail=ignore]/var/archives/5d47b5cc65f4e15d7d850a94/2022/2/24/621769372d3a6c63972b3fc6/master/1645701432.mp4|[select=\'v:1,a\':f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/4793731374078228?s_bl=1&s_oil=2&s_oilp=videoinfra_live_multi_e2o_2_vcache_pull_prod_&s_oilu=videoinfra_live_e2o_poc&s_ow=20&s_psm=1&s_r2f=1&s_sw=0&s_tids=1&s_vt=api-s&a=Abx_7pAPml40PHTg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, q=-1--1, 4000 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 4000000/0/4000000 buffer size: 8000000 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, q=-1--1, 4000 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 4000000/0/4000000 buffer size: 8000000 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 aac
[x11grab @ 0x55e6c5a5c300] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[pulse @ 0x55e6c5a4fbc0] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
frame=  960 fps= 24 q=3.0 q=3.0 size=N/A time=00:00:37.58 bitrate=N/A dup=54 drop=528 speed=0.942x
```

can somebody help me?

Comment: Share full report of ``ffmpeg -report -re -y -f pulse -ac 2 -i default -f x11grab -framerate 24 -video_size 1280x720 -draw_mouse 0 -i :44 -map 1:v -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset medium -b:v 4M -maxrate 4M -bufsize 8M -strict -2 -g 48 -r 24 -flags +global_header -t 5 -f flv "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/******?*****"``

Comment: Input #0, pulse, from 'default':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1645703131.903118, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
[x11grab @ 0x563825e6c180] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #1, x11grab, from ':44':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1645703131.961354, bitrate: 707788 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1280x720, 707788 kb/s, 24 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/****: Input/output error

Comment: That's not the full report of my command.